# Used recursive chown on the root directory

Tags: server, ssh, permissions, support

Im gonna need some help restoring my ssh settings as i screwed everything up by calling this command:

```
chown -R user /
```

At the moment im not able to access the site through ssh/ftp since the ownership of all the files have been changed. I dont want to reset every ownership but if i could get ssh working i would be able to create a backup of my files and then get a clean install of ubuntu on my server.

Here is the error that i get when im trying to restart ssh:

```
/var/run/sshd must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.
```

Im running ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Any help is very much appreciated.

P.S. I am able to run ssh commands on a browser based AJAX console that my hosting company (linode) provides.

Thanks

Comment: This is why you never login as root! If you were your own user, you wouldn't have been able to do this!

Comment: Well... maybe, but `chown` always has to be run as root (at least on my system. I don't know if this is configurable). So even if you're not logged in as root, you'd still be using `sudo` or something whenever you run a `chown` command.

Answer (score 4):

First to stop the error message change the owner of `/var/run/sshd` back to to root.

There might be more errors afterwoods, which probably mean you need to change other files too.

Answer (score 3):

**Wow.** You might be able to restore your permissions. It's a long shot but possibly worth considering if you've customised the install a lot.

Here's something I just concocted. This *should* (not tested) set every file in the root group to be owned by root.

```
sudo find / -group root -exec chown root {} \;
```

Comment: it is probably safer to restore from the backup. While this probably get close to fixing it, I am not sure if anybody has ever checked it. And furthermore, it only fixes the root group, not any other users.

Comment: From what I gather, there is no backup to restore from. He wants to make a backup once SSH'd in. For other files he *could* make a quick local install with a similar config do a funny find that prints the full path and owner, port that list to the broken server and then restore owners from that file. None of this is as "good" as a clean install or a real backup but time is often a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Well, best/easiest thing would be to restore your backup. You do backups, right?

Besides, this [blog post describes some approaches to reset permissions this via apt-get/dpkg](http://hyperlogos.org/Restoring-Permissions-Debian-System). Before trying this, you should do something like Oli posted (chown everything or a subset back to root again).

If you don't do backups, now is the time to start! ;)

Comment: Backups are good, but a lot of backup systems don't keep the owners.

Comment: @raphink: name one! Every serious backup system is able to backup/restore owner information (besides other file attributes).