# How to recover from chown on all the files?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, permissions, chown

I've just chowned all the computer. I wanted to chown a folder completely so I used the option `-R`. I forgot that I had used `su root` before and I was in the folder where everything is (`/` isn't it ?)

So, I chowned everything. When I did, there was no problem, I thought mine fixed (my folder was chowned... since everything was..) but when I restarted, ubuntu is dead.

Now that I want to reinstall it, I couldn't install it because when I went to something else (so I could change the partitions), I was unable to delete the partition of the old Ubuntu because it was mounted and being used (or being busy I don't know). It was mounted on `/cdrom`.

Did I kill my computer? How can I reinstall Ubuntu or Fedora or anything...

Comment: There's a couple of possible answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3008/used-recursive-chown-on-the-root-directory), but honestly you will probably end up doing a reinstall of Ubuntu.  You'll need to find a friend with a computer, download the Ubuntu install and burn it onto a USB...

Comment: Hi I have ubuntu on a USB but I can't install it since the computer insists on the fact that it is unmountable and hence the partitions cannot be formated or edited or resized or anything. I don't mind reinstalling a clean version of ubuntu. I only wish I could ..

Comment: If you have a different question please [open a new question](/questions/ask) or better yet find one that resembles yours.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution. I tried to reinstall Ubuntu with the same USB stick that installed it the first time, before I used chown upon everything. Either the USB stick was plugged in when I used the command or I don't know, it may have gotten corrupted.

I've made a new bootable stick with another Ubuntu version and it worked.

Thanks :)